# Very basic Python syntax

Tags: python

`char2int = {ch: ii for ii, ch in int2char.items()}`

I am just curious what `ch: ii` in the beginning the code above.

Thank you in advance.
Daniel

Comment: Check out dict comprehensions.

Comment: I just figured it out! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `int2char` dictionary contains key as integer and value as Characters like `{1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}`. In `char2int`, it needs to be converted to `{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}` i.e characters are key and integers as values.
The code just reverses it and assigning the keys and values to `char2int`. In short, it is equivalent to below,

```
int2char = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}

char2int = {}
for ii, ch in int2char.items():
    char2int[ch]= ii
```